# Window Phone Chat Application Server Side

Tags: windows-phone-7, window, chat

I want to develop a chat application in .net which is capable of sending text messages, files (PDF, images) etc.

Can you please tell me which one of these technology(WCF, ASP.net Web API(Sockets), Signal R) is best for server side.

Addtionally my client side is window phone application

Comment: Try asking a more specific question. This is pretty vague and unlikely to get a good answer. All those technologies are likely to be able to solve the issue you describe. Depending on your requirements, one may make more sense than another, but we don't know that without specific information.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Phone 7, here's [a sample application](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/07/15/a-wp7-conversation-view.html) with screenshots and some source code.

[image]

For Windows Phone 8 (I know you asked for Windows 7 only, but) there's a complete Sample that is built using `SignalR`. Here's the link to that sample. [Windows Phone 8 Chat Application using SignalR](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-8-Chat-1fa5eccf)